Ubuntu 24.4.1 LTS Sound skipping with VLC, Youtube, etc
Upgraded from Ubuntu 22.4.3 LTS.
Sound skipping with Ubuntu 24.4.1 LTS when using bluetooth earbuds with VLC, Youtube, or whatever the source.
When putting on speakers,no sound.
I have a USB soundcard that works fine with Ubuntu 22.4.3 LTS.
What is wrong with new Ubuntu LTS?

Workaround: For now, keep using the older kernel, and when you update, don't remove older kernels. Hopefully a future kernel update will fix the issue

Found that when upgrading to 24.4.1 LTS, Pulseaudio just muted the USB CM106 sound like device for speakers. I unmuted them.
Speakers work well now. Sound not skipping when using them.
Sound muting every 5 seconds for a fraction of a second only with Bluetooth earbuds now.
Everything fine with Windows 11.
Should have stayed with Ubuntu 22.4.3 LTS.
